# Traefik Stack Deploy/Service Create repeating tasks

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik

I am trying to deploy Traefik to my swarm cluster.
I am following some of this guide: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.7/user-guide/swarm-mode/
although I am using V2 of traefik, I can't seem to find a guide around deployment onto the swarm (even if I only want it on the management node).
When running the following docker command:

```
docker service create \
    --name traefik \
    --constraint=node.role==manager \
    --publish 80:80 --publish 8080:8080 \
    --mount type=bind,source=/var/run/docker.sock,target=/var/run/docker.sock \
    --network traefik-net \
    traefik \
    --docker \
    --docker.swarmMode \
    --docker.watch \
    --api
```

The creation process ends up in a repeating loop.
Looking at the `docker service ps` of that service, I get the following:

```
ID             NAME            IMAGE            NODE          DESIRED STATE   CURRENT STATE           ERROR                       PORTS
l5leeyfjqnvh   traefik.1       traefik:latest   ahomehost01   Ready           Ready 2 seconds ago                                
m0djg5q116kv    \_ traefik.1   traefik:latest   ahomehost01   Shutdown        Failed 3 seconds ago    "task: non-zero exit (1)"  
mcfzp4n0g4a0    \_ traefik.1   traefik:latest   ahomehost01   Shutdown        Failed 14 seconds ago   "task: non-zero exit (1)"  
rkl8ljv7qiwt    \_ traefik.1   traefik:latest   ahomehost01   Shutdown        Failed 25 seconds ago   "task: non-zero exit (1)"  
ngfy3j3124ev    \_ traefik.1   traefik:latest   ahomehost01   Shutdown        Failed 35 seconds ago   "task: non-zero exit (1)"
```

then running docker service logs on that service, gives me the following:

```
traefik.1.hry87mal3bcw@ahomehost01    | 2021/01/09 14:00:51 command traefik error: failed to decode configuration from flags: field not found, node: docker
```

Ideally i'd prefer to have this as a compose file for maintainability which I have created, but the same issues are occurring:

```
version: '3.3'
networks:
  swarm-network:
    driver: overlay
services:
  traefik:
    # The official v2 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    command: 
      - "--api.insecure=true" 
      - "--docker"
      - "--docker.swarmMode"
      - "--docker.watch"
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "80:80"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - swarm-network
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.backend=traefik"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.docker.swarm"
      - "traefik.docker.network=swarm-network"
```

Does anyone have an idea on V2 how I can deploy to the stack (manager only) or if it's even required and I have to take a different approach?

Comment: Is there a reason you build a v1.7 config and try to run it with v2.x? The parameters and syntax changed a lot... Wouldn't it make sense to directly build a v2.x configuration instead of starting with v1.x and migrating it to v2.x (see: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/migration/v1-to-v2/)? This is the link to the swarm mode config for the latest traefik version: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/docker/#docker-swarm-mode

Comment: I did not intend to build the config with v1.7, I was unable to find the V2 docs. Thank you for sharing them with me. It helped a lot to figure out the problem! Also worth noting that from the doc you sent, I also found this https://dockerswarm.rocks/traefik/ which answered the extra bits of information I needed.